# How to use access tokens for Gmail apps?

Tags: javascript, gmail-addons

I am trying to create a Gmail add-on scope [access token](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-scopes#access_tokens), my current goal is to somehow get the selected message's attachments and content in Spreadsheets.

```
function onGmailDo(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qsqQqHWQyVdbK-0LyBSac6eNqVZB1C0QxjE4xeBK_o/edit#gid=0"
  );

  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 100);

  var attachmentDetails = [];
  var attachments = mailMessage.getAttachments();

  for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
    attachmentDetails.push(
      "${attachments[k].getName()} :${attachments[k].getSize()}"
    );
  }
  sheet.appendRow([
    mailMessage.getSubject(),
    mailMessage.getDate(),
    mailMessage.getFrom(),
    attachmentDetails.join("\n"),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some helpful services were missing. Also I had to include the following scopes in my manifest file for authorization purposes.
Scopes: "https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
Corrected code:

```
function onGmailDo(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var text = e.parameters.text;
  var isHomepage = e.parameters.isHomepage === 'true';
  var card = createCard(text, isHomepage);
  var navigation = CardService.newNavigation()
      .updateCard(card);
  var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(navigation);
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qsqQqHWQyVdbK-0LyBSac6eNqVZB1C0QxjE4xeBK_o/edit#gid=0');

  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);


  var attachmentDetails = [];
  var attachments = mailMessage.getAttachments();
  
    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
    
       attachmentDetails.push(attachments[k].getName());
       attachmentDetails.push(attachments[k].getSize());
    }
    sheet.appendRow([mailMessage.getSubject(), mailMessage.getDate(), mailMessage.getFrom(), attachmentDetails.join('\n')]);
    
  return actionResponse.build();
}
```